# Subir archivos a un servidor diferente al del backend usando NodeJS/Express

Tags: nodejs, express, servidor, ftp

He estado intentando subir un archivo desde NodeJS a un servidor FTP diferente del que está alojado el backend en Express.

¿Alguien podría orientarme la manera en cómo hacerlo?

He visto que usan Multer o Express File Upload pero esto lo sube al mismo servidor donde está el backend.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar las librerias multer-ftp y ftp para poder hacer la subida de archivos a tu nuevo servidor de la siguiente manera:

Luego de que haces `npm i ftp multer multer-ftp` las podrias utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
const ftp = require('ftp');
const multer = require('multer');
const ftpStorage = require('multer-ftp');

const ftpClient = new ftp();
    ftpClient.connect({
        port: /*puerto del servidor*/,
        host: 'hostname',
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password'
    });

const storage = new ftpStorage({
        basepath: 'ubicacion destino del servidor',
        connection: ftpClient,
        destination: (req, file, options, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'path-destino');
        }
    });

const upload = multer({storage, fileFilter});

exports.upload = upload.single('nombre-campo-formulario');
```